# chroot with SSH and SFTP

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp, chroot

I'm stuck on something quite complicated it seems, but I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one to face this problem, still I can't seem to find someone having the same problem on any forum.

As said in the title I want to make a chroot for users that works with SSH and SFTP. I'm currently stuck with one or the other and that's not ok with me.

Following tutorials, I modified the sshd_config file and added this line as suggested:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

That allows me to connect when using a linux terminal but it's a bit tricky for windows user using putty even if it seems you can use it with psftp. But you can't use all the commands you put inside the jail env.

Does anyone has already figure this one out?

As stated before my chroot is working, so it's not really a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution reading another tutorial.

If anyone is troubled with this another time, in sshd_config, most tutorial juste leave the subsystem line in the file by default.

To resolve my issue I just did this:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

That did the work and I can now access my server in SSH and SFTP with the chrooted accounts.

It's always just after you post on a forum that you find a solution.

Have a good day everyone.